Need help setting camera zoom level using html5qrcode in React.js
I am using a library called html5qrcode to read barcodes, but it does not feature camera zoom setting and my customer is requesting to adjust the camera zoom to 2x;
Here is my code snippet related to the component in matter:
// hooks
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Html5Qrcode } from "html5-qrcode";

// icons
import { PlayCircleFilledWhite, StopCircle } from "@mui/icons-material";

// components
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const brConfig = { fps: 20, qrbox: { width: 400, height: 150 } };

let html5QrCode;

export const Scanner = (props) => {
  const [cameraStart, setCameraStart] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const startCamera = async () => {
      html5QrCode = new Html5Qrcode("reader");
      const qrCodeSuccessCallback = (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
        props.onResult(props.localAvoidMulti, decodedText, decodedResult);
      };

      try {
        const videoConstraints = {
          facingMode: "environment",
        };

        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: videoConstraints,
        });

        const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        const capabilities = videoTrack.getCapabilities();
        const settings = videoTrack.getSettings();

        console.log("Camera Capabilities: ", capabilities);
        console.log("Current Settings: ", settings);

        if (capabilities.zoom) {
          const minZoom = capabilities.zoom.min;
          const maxZoom = capabilities.zoom.max;
          const desiredZoom = 200; 
          const appliedZoom = Math.min(Math.max(minZoom, desiredZoom), maxZoom);

          const constraints = {
            advanced: [{ zoom: appliedZoom }],
          };

          await videoTrack.applyConstraints(constraints);

          // Confirm zoom is applied
        } else {
          const updatedSettings = videoTrack.getSettings();
          console.log(updatedSettings);
          console.warn("Zoom not supported by this camera.");
          alert("Zoom not supported by this camera.");
        }

        // Start the QR code scanner with the obtained video stream
        await html5QrCode.start(
          { deviceId: settings.deviceId },
          brConfig,
          qrCodeSuccessCallback
        );

        setCameraStart(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error starting the camera:", error);
        alert(`Error starting the camera: ${error.message}`);
        setCameraStart(false);
      }
    };

    startCamera();

    // Cleanup function
    return () => {
      handleStop();
    };
    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
  }, [props.localAvoidMulti]);

  const handleClickAdvanced = async () => {
    const qrCodeSuccessCallback = (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
      props.onResult(decodedText);
      handleStop();
    };

    try {
      const videoConstraints = {
        facingMode: "environment",
      };

      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: videoConstraints,
      });

      const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      const capabilities = videoTrack.getCapabilities();
      const settings = videoTrack.getSettings();

      console.log("Camera Capabilities: ", capabilities);
      console.log("Current Settings: ", settings);

      // Check if zoom is supported and apply a valid zoom level
      if (capabilities.zoom) {
        const minZoom = capabilities.zoom.min;
        const maxZoom = capabilities.zoom.max;
        const desiredZoom = 150; // Setting a value within the supported range
        const appliedZoom = Math.min(Math.max(minZoom, desiredZoom), maxZoom);

        const constraints = {
          advanced: [{ zoom: appliedZoom }],
        };

        await videoTrack.applyConstraints(constraints);

        // Confirm zoom is applied
      } else {
        console.warn("Zoom not supported by this camera.");
        alert("Zoom not supported by this camera.");
      }

      await html5QrCode.start(
        { deviceId: settings.deviceId },
        brConfig,
        qrCodeSuccessCallback
      );

      const oldRegion = document.getElementById("qr-shaded-region");
      if (oldRegion) oldRegion.innerHTML = "";

      setCameraStart(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error starting the camera:", error);
      alert(`Error starting the camera: ${error.message}`);
      setCameraStart(false);
    }
  };

  const handleStop = () => {
    try {
      if (html5QrCode) {
        html5QrCode
          .stop()
          .then(() => {
            if (html5QrCode) {
              html5QrCode.clear();
            }
            setCameraStart(false);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            setCameraStart(false);
          });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setCameraStart(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <div id="reader" width="100%"></div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
          marginTop: "10px",
        }}
      >
        {!cameraStart ? (
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            className="button save-btn"
            onClick={handleClickAdvanced}
            color="success"
          >
            <PlayCircleFilledWhite
              sx={{ fontSize: "50px" }}
              className="save-icon"
            />
            Iniciar
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <StopCircle
            onClick={handleStop}
            sx={{ fontSize: "50px", color: "red" }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Thanks in advance :)
I used navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to help ajust the zoom, it does work with desktop browser, but not in my apk application (android web view) for android tablet.
